# How to change default symbol sequence in Plolty?

Tags: python, plotly, default, plotly-python

How do I change the default symbol sequence in Plotly? I am trying with the following MWE

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.graph_objects as go

my_template = pio.templates['ggplot2'] # Copy this template.
# Now modify some specific settings of the template.
my_template.data.scatter = [
    go.Scatter(
        marker = dict(size=22),
        symbol_sequence = ['circle', 'square', 'diamond', 'cross', 'x', 'star'],
    )
]
pio.templates.default = my_template # Set my template as default.

fig = px.line(
    data_frame = px.data.gapminder(),
    x = "year",
    y = "lifeExp",
    color = "country",
    symbol = "continent",
)

fig.show()
```

This raises the error

```
ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.Scatter: 'symbol'
```

I have `plotly.__version__` == `5.3.1`.

I have also noticed that in this MWE the default marker size is not working for some reason, the value I insert is ignored.

Comment: that looks correct. Can you provide a sample data set here so I can debug?

Comment: Can you try `marker_symbol` instead of `symbol_sequence`, please?

Comment: @chitown88 that code already fails. I will add a complete MWE now. @rftr `marker_symbol` also fails.

Comment: what do you mean it already fails?

Comment: That if you run that code, an error is raised.

Comment: you should include the error in your post

Comment: `plotly.__version__` prints `5.3.1`.

Comment: I have added a full MWE that fails for me, so you can try it.

Comment: In your template definition, try to set the symbols in the marker `dict`: `marker=dict(size=22, symbol=['circle', 'square', 'diamond', 'cross', 'x', 'star'])` and delete `symbol_sequence` from the definition.

Comment: @rftr if I do that `fig.show()` opens a blank tab in the browser, nothing is shown. If I `print(fig)` it is not empty, but it seems there is something wrong.

Comment: Does this MWE work for you? Maybe in another version of Plotly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [creating themes](https://plotly.com/python/templates/#creating-themes) you can see that:

> If a trace type property is set to a list of more than one trace, then
> the default properties are cycled as more traces are added to the
> figure.

So you can either set up multiple `go.Scatter()` with different replacements for `"diamond"` as `symbol` in:

```
symbol_template.data.scatter = [
    go.Scatter(marker=dict(symbol="diamond", size=10)),
    go.Scatter(marker=dict(symbol="square", size=10)),
    go.Scatter(marker=dict(symbol="circle", size=10)),
]
```

Or you can use a list comprehension with a specified sequence like so:

```
new_sequence = ['pentagon', 'hexagram', 'star', 'diamond', 'hourglass', 'bowtie', 'square']

my_template.data.scatter = [
    go.Scatter(marker=dict(symbol=s, size=12)) for s in new_sequence
]
```

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.graph_objects as go

my_template = pio.templates['ggplot2'] 

new_sequence = ['pentagon', 'hexagram', 'star', 'diamond', 'hourglass', 'bowtie', 'square']

my_template.data.scatter = [
    go.Scatter(marker=dict(symbol=s, size=12)) for s in new_sequence
]

pio.templates.default = my_template

df = px.data.gapminder()
df = df.tail(100)

fig = px.line(
    data_frame = df,
    x = "year",
    y = "lifeExp",
    color = "country",
    symbol = "continent",
)

fig.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

Looking through the templates, there doesn't seem to be a marker size or sequence in the templates themselves. Why not just use the `.update_traces()` to adjust the marker size, and put the symbol sequence in the `px.line()`?

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.graph_objects as go

my_template = pio.templates['ggplot2'] # Copy this template.
pio.templates.default = my_template # Set my template as default.

fig = px.line(
    data_frame = px.data.gapminder(),
    x = "year",
    y = "lifeExp",
    color = "country",
    symbol = "continent",
    symbol_sequence = ['circle', 'square', 'diamond', 'cross', 'x', 'star']

)

fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=22))
fig.show()
```

**Original:**

[image]

**After adding additional parameters:**

[image]

Comment: Looking at [the documentation](https://plotly.com/python/templates/#the-template-data-property) it should be possible to do what I want. Furthermore, I don't want to manually change each property in each figure I create. That's why templates are for after all.

Comment: Well the question is how to change the default symbol sequence. It may not be the solution you like, but it is a solution that addresses it. Not sure why it’s downvoted.

Comment: Your answer does not change the default symbols sequence, it just changes the sequence in one figure.